# replacing particular set of characters from a string in java

Tags: java

I have a string (say)

```
int t=5;
```

I want to replace the identifier `'t'` in above string with some other String say `"abc"`. using the `replaceAll()` or `replace()` methods of String in java replaces char 't' in int as well. so the output that i get is

```
"inabc abc=5;"
```

I want to replace the identifier only. please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Decide exactly what you want to replace. Do you want to replace the "t" in "tin"? "+t+"? "$t$"? "alphabet"? "titan"? What if the whole string is just "t"? Java does not have a built-in library for parsing Java source code, so if you want to parse Java source code, you're in for a lot of work (or finding a library for it).

Comment: If you are trying to build tool which would let you rename your variables then you don't have to. Just use IDE like Eclipse, mark variable you want to replace (or set cursor on it) and pick `Refactor` -> `Rename..`.

Comment: If you don't want to use IDE functionality then you need to create your own Java parser. Regex is not best tool for this. What if variables will have names same as some classes like `String String = "foo";`?

Comment: Other example of why regex would not be good for this are shadowed variables for instance  `int i = 1; {int i = 2; i++}` Which `i` should be renamed?

Comment: I am actually reading a .java file and then storing all the identifiers of this .java code into a set in pass 1. And then in pass 2 i am using this set to replace the identifiers by the ceaser cipher equivalent of that identifier. Yeah i know that if the identifiers are same as the java classes name, it wont work. so could you please suggest me a parser that can actually find all the identifiers. Thnx

Comment: I didn't work with any particular Java parser so I can't suggest you anything specific but I heard good opinions about [JavaCC](https://javacc.java.net/) and in case you are willing to write your own parser [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) should be very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the word anchor (`\b`) as in:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\bt\\b", "abc");
```

A regex has no notion of a word!

---

However, this will only ever bring you so far; this regex may fail on some more complicated constructs. You really want to use a parser if you want more complex substitutions; parboiled, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work-

```
yourString.replace(" t", " abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regexp to replace all occurrences of a variable, assuming that before and after the name there cannot be any word-like character:

```
    String s = "int t=5";

    String s2 = s.replaceAll("(?<!\\w)t(?!\\w)", "abc");
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can change "t=" to "abc=".

```
str.replace("t=", "abc=");
```

Comment: What about cases where there are one or more spaces between `t` and `=`? Or if `t` is last character in some other word like `it=`?

Comment: @Pshemo This question is only need to change the second "t" to "abc", I think this is the quick way. If there are other requirements use regex is the best way.

Comment: For this particular case, yes your solution will work, but it seems that this is only example of what OP is really trying to do, so try to add more general answer as well.